# Set transparent background in joomla facebook plugin

Tags: php, css

(I am just php, css amateur so please be lenient ;) )

I am trying to remove white background from jooma Simpl Facebook plugin at our page

http://cpband.itvp.eu/

I have found that i have to remove

background: from q-VUQrv_B7w.css ._4-u8 and ._2lqg

at two places. Which can be done easily in browser, but I am not able to find that at server side. I asume that this file is loaded from somewhere (facebook) and I am not able to edit it. Would it be possible force these parameters by myself?

Thanks for tips!

Comment: There isn't any option to set a background color (or make it transparent). You're using the Facebook Page Plugin The complete list of options can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their current implementation, Facebook doesn't allow you to change the background color from white. The full list of attributes that they do allow are on their developer docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#settings